# How to run the Chrome Beta version with ChromeDriver using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

i am trying to run the chrome beta version with selenium Web-driver.
When i run the test case i got the following error on console see image please:

[image: click here to see exception]

I have added following lines in the node config file:

```
    {
"capabilities": [

    {
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "webdriver.chrome.driver":"drive:\selenium\chromedriver.exe",
        "chromeOptions": "drive:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe",

    }

]
```

I am using following setup:

```
Selenium=2.53
chrome Web-driver= 80_0_3987_16
Google chrome= 80.0.3987.66 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)
```

we have Hub and Node setup and automated test suit executed from GO cicd Server.
any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run either of the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser variant among:

- *Chrome Canary*
- Chrome from *Dev Channel*
- Raw build of *Chromium for Windows x64*

You need to to download the latest *Chromium* binary from either of the official repositories:

- [The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium)
- [chromium.appspot](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/)
- [Chrome Canary - Nightly build for developers](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/canary/)

and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  public class A_Chrome_Canary {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
          opt.setBinary("C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Google
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Chrome_Canary]

Comment: thanks for the answer @DabanjanB. actually i am trying to run google chrome beta version not canary. it would be really help if you guide me on how setup google chrome beta.

Comment: i access above official repositories links and i have already download and installed beta chrome.

Comment: @Asad I think initiating canary and canary will involve the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
chrome_options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome Beta/Application/chrome.exe"
```