# How to use Google Chrome Beta with RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72793082/2554330, there are some bugs in the latest version of `chromedriver` that have been fixed in the version that works with Google Chrome Beta, so I'd like to try the beta.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65975577/2554330 shows how to run Google Chrome Beta from Javascript.  I'd like to do the same from RSelenium, but I can't spot an equivalent of `chrome_options.binary_location`.

How do I specify the Chrome location when using RSelenium?

Comment: You may pass a `binary` option to specify binary location in the `extraCapabilities` argument when calling `remoteDriver`. I found [this issue](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/31#issuecomment-60505054) may be related.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very helpful.  If you want the bounty, please write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following codes:

```
cPath <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
ecap <- list(chromeOptions = list("binary" = cPath))
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", extraCapabilities = ecap)
remDr$open()
```

Note that `startServer()` func is now defunct.

These were obtained from [this comment](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/31#issuecomment-60505054) by the author of `RSelenium`.

Comment: Been a while, thanks for link to  updated RSelenium

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the chromedriver is wherever you place it and the beta browser is wherever it gets installed. It's been a long time since I used r/selenium, so slashes maybe the wrong way

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer(args = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe")
            , log = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  browserName = "chrome",
  extraCapabilities = list("chrome.binary" = "C:\\Program Files\\ChromeBeta\\chrome.exe")
)
remDr$open()

head(remDr$sessionInfo)
```